# Is it possible to "debug" a release build of a C# app in VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel, debugging, add-in

I have an excel addin that works fine in debug and release mode when I build / run from VS2010. However, when I deploy it using a windows installer it doesn't operate properly.

I'm not sure what the problem is or even if "debugging" the release code will help.

Any tips on how I might find what the problem is?

**EDIT**

What I mean by "doesn't operate properly" is that when i hit buttons etc nothing happens and it just hangs.

Thanks

Comment: Try to be more specific: in what way it doesn't operate properly?

Comment: May be some of the dependency in missing in your installer..

Comment: What I do when releasing a C# application is create a logger, when an error occurs it writes the errors to a text file, so say you stick some try - catches in your program; if you catch an error, it will log it to the textbox.

Comment: It could alse be some settings that is not correct, e.g. connection strings to databases

Answer (score 31):

In higher version of Visual Studio, debug release build enabled, when I uncheck "enable just my code" in following menu "tools -> options-> debugging -> general"

[image]

Answer (score 8):

you also need to ensure the Optimize code is unchecked
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Visual Studio 2019 has both checked off in release by default in all csproj files. I've found "allow own code" but somehow this one slipped.

Answer (score 0):

Given you have configured your release build to emit debug symbols then yes you should be able to simply [attach a debugger to the process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6wf8e4z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and step through it.

Comment: When I try to attache to process I get an error telling me that the module was bult either iwth optimizations enabled or without debug info. Is it possible to build debug into into a release build?

Comment: Also, it seems to hang whenever I reference Properties.Settings

Comment: @PatMustard again, yes but you have to make sure you have debug information - Project Properties > Build > Advanced > Debug Info = full. Hanging could be a result of many issues...most probably you have an infinite loop somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, James. In my solution, I have three dlls, the add-in, an rtdserver and a shared one. All of these have debugging info = full but I still get the error about debug info from VS when I go tools -> attach to process. Am I forgetting something?

Comment: It it really a 'release' build if you're emitting debug symbols and not optimizing it? Just because you call the configuration 'release' doesn't mean it is.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/debugging-optimized-code/

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-optimized-code?view=vs-2019